# is it possible to have a members of subclasses in superclass in c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

My goal here was, instead of placing all methods in ServerInterface(superclass), i wanted to place the methods in child classes to organize the code better.

```
class ServerInterface
{
public:
    Router* router = new Router();
    Client* client = new Client();
    ServerInterface() {

    } //Creates new Router and Client instance
};

class Router : public ServerInterface
{
public:
    Router() {}
    void randomRouterFunction() {}
};

class Client : public ServerInterface
{
public:
    Client() {}
    virtual void randomClientFunction() {};
};



class ProductionServer : public ServerInterface
{
public:
    ProductionServer() {}
};

int main() {
    ProductionServer* productionServer = new ProductionServer();
    productionServer->router->randomRouterFunction(); //causes it to not debug
    return 0;
}
```

In my situation I am only allowed to access to `ProductionServer` which has to inherit from `ServerInterface` in my code.
So instead of calling `productionServer->randomRouterFunction()` or `productionServer->randomClientFunction()`, i wanted to be able to call `productionServer->Router->randomRouterFunction()` etc

Even though intellisense tells me that it's all working fine, trying to run my code i recieve

> main:289:20: error: 'class ProductionServer' has no member named
> 'router'
>
> productionServer->router->randomRouterFunction();

Is this even feasible to accomplish? The reason for thinking it may not work is cause the superclass creates a member of Router which is the child class, and then the router child class creates another superclass since it inherits it, which then creats another router child class in the superclass.... and it would be an infinite loop? XD

ps. The randomFunction() could be any method, just used as an example.

Comment: We can't actually see the broken code, CoffeDev... present your [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes) ?

Comment: _" the superclass creates a member of Router which is the child class"_ It does not; you have a `Router*`, not a `Router`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, that would be more like `class ProductionServer undeclared`.... and there's no evidence of multiple headers here anyway, let alone circular dependencies. Let's not jump the gun, eh?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings oh sorry missed it, will edit :D

Comment: Your code example is improving. Please add a `main()` method so that we can compile and run it ourselves without any modifications.

Comment: *Can* you — yes (with some fixes). Does it make sense? Almost certainly no. Think about it: at the moment, both your `Router` and your `Client` class contain `Router` and `Client` members themselves. Is this meaningful?

Comment: Does it make sense for `Router` to subclass `ServerInterface`? Same for `Client`? A big part of OO is deciding the responsibility for each class. I think a `ProductionServer` that subclasses `ServerInterface` makes a lot of sense, but not `Router` or `Client`.

Comment: will add runnable code :D It's actually such a big library that i just took some snippets for showcase, will edit in a second XD

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I see how you mean, thats a very good point. In the beginning i had all the methods inside ServerInterface, and there was 100+ functions, so i wanted to find a way to organize the code more into groups so it could be like ServerInterface->Group1->anyFunctionInside();

Comment: @CoffeDev It sounds like your ServerInterface does need broken up. I think "groups" isn't the right way, though. Instead, look for several functions that support a similar purpose. Then instead of naming them `Group1`, `Group2`, etc. name them according to that mutal purpose.

Comment: @CoffeDev To get you thinking about how to split up your ServerInterface class, I suggest you read about the Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the design. You can compile this but when you create a `ProductionServer` it will instantiate a `ServerInterface` which will create a `Router` and a `Client` and those will both also instantiate a `ServerInterface` that will create a `Router` and a `Client` and so on - until you get a stack overflow.

In order to get this in some working condition, you need to add something that breaks that cycle so that it doesn't instantiate `Router`s and `Client`s endlessly.

Comment: Oh that was what i was afraid of :( Is there any other way to group in a similar fashion, witthout having to place all methods in the ServerInterface?

Comment: @CoffeDev There are always options but it'll be easier to advice with some real world functions. One option is [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) but then you loose some other advatages.

Comment: I can confirm by the way, the reason for it not compiling was the exact reason you mentioned! The way i made it work was to name ServerInterface to SuperServerInterface, and have a child class that is named ServerInterface which instead creates the router and client, so no infinite loops and voila it worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CoffeDev You are welcome, but I actually _did_ compile it successfully (with added forward declarations for `Router` and `Client`). It fails in run-time due to stack overflow. I may have grabbed one of your earlier edits of the code. I turned the raw pointers into smart pointers like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/G5sTqW) and noticed that it exited badly and spotted the endless creation cycle.

Comment: i did something similar to this https://godbolt.org/z/xo3s4z, to avoid endless loops. The library i am using in my microcontroller is so huge and a mess that it's hard to make a good showcase for it XD

Comment: @CoffeDev Why does `ServerInterface` have a `Client`? Usually the server and client are two wholly separate things. I think you need to continue thinking about how you separate things out in your classes and just as importantly how the classes related. Also, I strongly suggest finding a better name than `SuperServerInterface`. Names should describe what their purpose is and the prefix "Super" adds no meaning to the purpose of this interface.